# Runtime calculation without knowing the execution started

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to calculate the runtime of multiple recorders. There can be infinitely recorders running at the same time.

When I have a start and end point I get the expected result with the following code snippet.

```
val ds2 = ds
      .withColumn("started", when($"status" === "start", 1).otherwise(lit(0)))
      .withColumn("stopped", when($"status" === "stop", -1).otherwise(lit(0)))
      .withColumn("engFlag", when($"started" === 1, $"started").otherwise($"stopped"))
      .withColumn("engWindow", sum($"engFlag").over(Window.orderBy($"timestamp")))
      .withColumn("runtime", when($"engWindow" > 0,
        (unix_timestamp(lead($"timestamp", 1).over(Window.orderBy($"timestamp"))) - unix_timestamp($"timestamp"))/60*$"engWindow").otherwise(lit(0)))
```

Input data:

```
val ds_working = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
      ("2017-01-01 06:00:00", "start", "1"),
      ("2017-01-01 07:00:00", "start", "2"),
      ("2017-01-01 08:00:00", "foo", "2"),
      ("2017-01-01 09:00:00", "blub", "2"),
      ("2017-01-01 10:00:00", "stop", "3"),
      ("2017-01-01 11:00:00", null, "3"),
      ("2017-01-01 12:00:00", "ASC_c", "4"),
      ("2017-01-01 13:00:00", "stop", "5" ),
      ("2017-01-01 14:00:00", null, "3"),
      ("2017-01-01 15:00:00", "ASC_c", "4")
    )).toDF("timestamp", "status", "msg")
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+------+---+-------+-------+-------+---------+-------+
|          timestamp|status|msg|started|stopped|engFlag|engWindow|runtime|
+-------------------+------+---+-------+-------+-------+---------+-------+
|2017-01-01 06:00:00| start|  1|      1|      0|      1|        1|   60.0|
|2017-01-01 07:00:00| start|  2|      1|      0|      1|        2|  120.0|
|2017-01-01 08:00:00|   foo|  2|      0|      0|      0|        2|  120.0|
|2017-01-01 09:00:00|  blub|  2|      0|      0|      0|        2|  120.0|
|2017-01-01 10:00:00|  stop|  3|      0|     -1|     -1|        1|   60.0|
|2017-01-01 11:00:00|  null|  3|      0|      0|      0|        1|   60.0|
|2017-01-01 12:00:00| ASC_c|  4|      0|      0|      0|        1|   60.0|
|2017-01-01 13:00:00|  stop|  5|      0|     -1|     -1|        0|    0.0|
|2017-01-01 14:00:00|  null|  3|      0|      0|      0|        0|    0.0|
|2017-01-01 15:00:00| ASC_c|  4|      0|      0|      0|        0|    0.0|
+-------------------+------+---+-------+-------+-------+---------+-------+
```

Now to my problem:
I have no idea how to calculate the runtime if I start calculating in the middle of a running recorder. That means I dont see the start flag but a stop flag. Which indicates that in the past a start flag must have happened.

Data:

```
val ds_notworking = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
      ("2017-01-01 02:00:00", "foo", "1"),
      ("2017-01-01 03:00:00", null, "2"),
      ("2017-01-01 04:00:00", "stop", "1"),
      ("2017-01-01 05:00:00", "stop", "2"),
      ("2017-01-01 06:00:00", "start", "1"),
      ("2017-01-01 07:00:00", "start", "2"),
      ("2017-01-01 08:00:00", "foo", "2"),
      ("2017-01-01 09:00:00", "blub", "2"),
      ("2017-01-01 10:00:00", "stop", "3"),
      ("2017-01-01 11:00:00", null, "3"),
      ("2017-01-01 12:00:00", "ASC_c", "4"),
      ("2017-01-01 13:00:00", "stop", "5" ),
      ("2017-01-01 14:00:00", null, "3"),
      ("2017-01-01 15:00:00", "ASC_c", "4"),
    )).toDF("timestamp", "status", "msg")
```

Wanted output:

```
+-------------------+------+---+-------+-------+---------+-----+
|          timestamp|status|msg|started|stopped|engWindow|runt |
+-------------------+------+---+-------+-------+---------+-----+
|2017-01-01 02:00:00|   foo|  1|      0|      0|        0| 120 |
|2017-01-01 03:00:00|  null|  2|      0|      0|        0| 120 |
|2017-01-01 04:00:00|  stop|  1|      0|     -1|       -1|  60 |
|2017-01-01 05:00:00|  stop|  2|      0|     -1|       -1|   0 |
|2017-01-01 06:00:00| start|  1|      1|      0|        1|  60 |
|2017-01-01 07:00:00| start|  2|      1|      0|        1| 120 |
|2017-01-01 08:00:00|   foo|  2|      0|      0|        0| 120 |
|2017-01-01 09:00:00|  blub|  2|      0|      0|        0| 120 |
|2017-01-01 10:00:00|  stop|  3|      0|     -1|       -1|  60 |
|2017-01-01 11:00:00|  null|  3|      0|      0|        0|  60 |
|2017-01-01 12:00:00| ASC_c|  4|      0|      0|        0|  60 |
|2017-01-01 13:00:00|  stop|  5|      0|     -1|       -1|   0 |
|2017-01-01 14:00:00|  null|  3|      0|      0|        0|   0 |
|2017-01-01 15:00:00| ASC_c|  4|      0|      0|        0|   0 |
+-------------------+------+---+-------+-------+---------+-----+
```

I have solved this problem when only one instance of recorder can run at the same time with:

```
 .withColumn("engWindow", last($"engFlag", true).over(systemWindow.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)))
```

But with 2 or more instances sadly I have no clue how to accomplish this.
It would be nice if someone could point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. I was thinking about this way to complicated.
Though I am not sure yet if there are any cases where this approach will not work.

I am summarizing the flags like I did in the working example, order the data descending by timestamp, find the minimum value and add this value to the current value. This should always indicate the correct number of running recorders.

```
 val ds2 = ds_notworking
      .withColumn("started", when($"status" === "start", 1).otherwise(lit(0)))
      .withColumn("stopped", when($"status" === "stop", -1).otherwise(lit(0)))
      .withColumn("engFlag", when($"started" === 1, $"started").otherwise($"stopped"))
      .withColumn("engWindow", sum($"engFlag").over(Window.orderBy($"timestamp")))
      .withColumn("newEngWindow", $"engWindow" - min($"engWindow").over(Window.orderBy($"timestamp".desc)))
      .withColumn("runtime2", when($"newEngWindow" > 0,
        (unix_timestamp(lead($"timestamp", 1).over(Window.orderBy($"timestamp"))) - unix_timestamp($"timestamp"))/60*$"newEngWindow").otherwise(lit(0)))
```

EDIT: maybe this would be more correct to calculate the minimun value and apply it to the entire window.

```
.withColumn("test1", last(min($"engWindow").over(Window.orderBy($"timestamp"))).over(Window.orderBy($"timestamp").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)))
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+------+---+-------+-------+-------+---------+------------+--------+
|          timestamp|status|msg|started|stopped|engFlag|engWindow|newEngWindow|runtime2|
+-------------------+------+---+-------+-------+-------+---------+------------+--------+
|2017-01-01 02:00:00|   foo|  1|      0|      0|      0|        0|           2|   120.0|
|2017-01-01 03:00:00|  null|  2|      0|      0|      0|        0|           2|   120.0|
|2017-01-01 04:00:00|  stop|  1|      0|     -1|     -1|       -1|           1|    60.0|
|2017-01-01 05:00:00|  stop|  2|      0|     -1|     -1|       -2|           0|     0.0|
|2017-01-01 06:00:00| start|  1|      1|      0|      1|       -1|           1|    60.0|
|2017-01-01 07:00:00| start|  2|      1|      0|      1|        0|           2|   120.0|
|2017-01-01 08:00:00|   foo|  2|      0|      0|      0|        0|           2|   120.0|
|2017-01-01 09:00:00|  blub|  2|      0|      0|      0|        0|           2|   120.0|
|2017-01-01 10:00:00|  stop|  3|      0|     -1|     -1|       -1|           1|    60.0|
|2017-01-01 11:00:00|  null|  3|      0|      0|      0|       -1|           1|    60.0|
|2017-01-01 12:00:00| ASC_c|  4|      0|      0|      0|       -1|           1|    60.0|
|2017-01-01 13:00:00|  stop|  5|      0|     -1|     -1|       -2|           0|     0.0|
|2017-01-01 14:00:00|  null|  3|      0|      0|      0|       -2|           0|     0.0|
|2017-01-01 15:00:00| ASC_c|  4|      0|      0|      0|       -2|           0|     0.0|
+-------------------+------+---+-------+-------+-------+---------+------------+--------+
```